# App crashes when table menu item selected in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling

The app crashes in simulator when one item is pressed on the slide out menu (created with table view), I've tried deleting connections between UI and IB and remaking them incase this is the issue, but it hasn't solved it.

This is the error code that comes out:

```
View Controller is : <AKSwiftSlideMenu.HomeVC: 0x7fa6c5e05b90> 
Calculate your own repayment
2017-02-08 17:36:13.782 AKSwiftSlideMenu[37086:3161182] Unknown class     TrackerVC in Interface Builder file.
2017-02-08 17:36:13.801 AKSwiftSlideMenu[37086:3161182] *** Terminating     app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:     '[<UIViewController 0x7fa6c5d1f920> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key AnnualInterestInput.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9a0d4b     __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a40221e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9a0c99 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000109f109df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
4   UIKit                               0x000000010af5f293 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
5   UIKit                               0x000000010b1d379e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9459e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
7   UIKit                               0x000000010b1d2122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
8   UIKit                               0x000000010af659c5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
9   UIKit                               0x000000010af662e7 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
10  UIKit                               0x000000010af6661c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
11  UIKit                               0x000000010af6d062 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 118
12  UIKit                               0x000000010af981d3 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1290
13  UIKit                               0x000000010afa8e48 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 697
14  UIKit                               0x000000010afa9fdb -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
15  UIKit                               0x000000010b1a0dd7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
16  UIKit                               0x000000010ae89ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f85fbf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f853440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f8532be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f7e1318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f80e3ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
22  UIKit                               0x000000010adef7f0 _afterCACommitHandler + 346
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a945267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9451d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a929f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a929884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f02fa6f GSEventRunModal + 161
28  UIKit                               0x000000010adc4c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
29  AKSwiftSlideMenu                    0x0000000109e0401f main + 111
30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e09f68d start + 1
31  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: check your `AnnualInterestInput` Outlet. One of your view is connected with it. But it didn't declare in your class or you removed it from your class.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, it most probably is that one of your views is connected to an outlet named `AnnualInterestInput` that was deleted from the class.

If by deleting all the outlets and reconnecting them to the view controller didn't work it out, then it may be due to a wrong class in the xib.

This means that you have set a wrong class in the xib or storyboard and it's not able to found the key. If the class is still correct, check if the module is correct!

This line is what gives me a hint that this could be the problem:

`2017-02-08 17:36:13.782 AKSwiftSlideMenu[37086:3161182] Unknown class     TrackerVC in Interface Builder file.`

Comment: Inside the storyboard or swift, select the controller and check the class that is on the third tab. It says "custom class"